# Passing in and modifying an array in a function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have been looking at other posts and trying to get this working for a bit, but can't seem to manage it.

Basically I want to pass a "char myArray[10]" though into a function, have the function assign the values and then hand it back. It generally looks like this at the moment:

```
int MyClass::GetArray(char array[10])
{   
    char p[10];
    ... // a value is assigned to p
    memcpy(&array, &p, sizeof(p)); // Here array ends up being 0x3232323232323232 <Error reading characters of string.>

    return 0;
}
```

Called with:

```
    char array[10];
    myclass.GetArray(array);
```

So, I assume I need to pass the array through as a reference to the array[10] created before calling the function. But for that I am unsure how to create a pointer to a fixed array without making it either a general char* pointer or a pointer to an array of chars.

Secondly is the memcpy error (in the code comments above). I'm not sure if that is related or not though.

Comment: Use `std::array` in place of built-in arrays. It has a `size` function (you don't know the size of the parameter in your example) and it supports assignment.

Comment: In memcpy, pass in `array` instead of `&array`. It'll decay to a pointer to the first element. Same for `p`. Why are you copying the memory anyway? (Actually, it could only (easily) make sense if you were passing a reference to the array, but that's what you're asking about, so nevermind~)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then thing is that when you pass an array to a function, it decays to a pointer. So when you use the address-of operator `&` on `array` in the function, you're taking the address of the pointer, meaning you get a pointer to a pointer.

That, by the way, leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Other than that it's all okay, you don't have to pass the array (or rather, pointer) by reference. It's just not very... C++-ish. :)

Comment: Okie. Removing the refernce(&) as you and Mohammad suggested works perfectly. But it sounds like you might have a better suggestion on how to do this? :)  @chris Yeah, I didn't realise that the compiler ignored that value. For my program though everything will be 10 bytes and the char array[10] will be the only array passed through :)

Comment: @user1539405 I would suggest using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) even if it's the only array you use. The formal parameter to the function would then need to passed by reference, e.g. `std::array<char, 10>& array`. Using a standard contain like `std::array` would keep you from making mistakes like (old C-style) arrays decaying to pointers.

Comment: All right, will update it to an std array. And report back when I somehow screw it up ;)